# Bind click event of a button to drop function of a Droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, click, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list with hyperlinks inside each list item. This list is not-sortable but can be dropped onto a div with ID #droppable. Now if I drag & drop any of the list item, then the function provided in the droppable executes perfectly. So far, so good. Instead of dragging the list item, I want to click on it to execute the same droppable function, so that I can pass the item of the list-item & if needed, the hyperlink id as well. But this is not working.

Here is the complete code that I have tried so far: (I have jQuery & jQuery UI)

```
<ul id="my_list">
<li id="li1"><a href="#" id="a1">Link</a></li>
<li id="li2"><a href="#" id="a2">Link</a></li>
<li id="li3"><a href="#" id="a3">Link</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="droppable"></div>


$("#my_list li, #my_list li a").bind( "click", function(event, ui) {

        Drop(event, ui); //Doesnt work

        return false;
});

//I also tried the following, but doesnt work
$("#my_list li, #my_list li a").on( "click", function(event, ui) {

        Drop(event, ui); //Doesnt work

        return false;
});

$("#droppable").droppable({

        drop: function(event, ui) {

            Drop(event, ui);
        }       
}); 


function Drop(event, ui) {

    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(draggableId + draggableId); //This alert fires correctly when the droppable is dropped but not if the hyperlink in #my_list is clicked.

};
```

Comment: `.bind( "click", function(event, ui) { ... }` will leave the `ui` parameter undefined, so when you pass that parameter to `Drop(event, ui)` and then within `Drop()` do `ui.draggable.attr("id")` what you're actually doing is `undefined.draggable.attr("id")` which will give an error.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. So can you please tell me how to solve this? I just got started with the draggables/droppables & I am completely novice in it. I Googled a lot, but seems like there's no record of a solution nor even a question for this!